# Get color amount with get-image-colors package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [get-image-colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-image-colors) package

```
"get-image-colors": "^2.0.0"
```

to get color amount from png and gif. My code is:

```
const getColors = require('get-image-colors')

getColors('https://i.imgur.com/CypfPvl.png')
    .then(colors => {
        console.log(colors.length);
    });
```

and it show me 5 although image is only black:

[image]

What I do wrong?

value of `colors` is

```
[
  Color { _rgb: [ 4, 4, 4, 1, _clipped: false ] },
  Color { _rgb: [ 8, 4, 4, 1, _clipped: false ] },
  Color { _rgb: [ 8, 4, 4, 1, _clipped: false ] },
  Color { _rgb: [ 8, 4, 4, 1, _clipped: false ] },
  Color { _rgb: [ 8, 4, 4, 1, _clipped: false ] }
]
```

Comment: What is the value of `colors` ?

Comment: Take a look at edit

Comment: This library does not exactly what you assume it does. 5 is the default `count` parameter which you can tweak. So the library tries to extract color palette from an image and give you back 5 distinct colors (or as many as you like).

Comment: then why in this array rgb are not equal when i pass just black image

Comment: is there some alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to make it work with linked package but in its dependiecies I found "getPixels" package.

I used and it gave me an ndarray of pixels with its rgb. Then I converted this ndarray thing to regular array of arrays. Then in loop I checked if every nested arrays is equal by converting it to json string:

```
const getPixels = require("get-pixels");

//1px only black https://i.imgur.com/dStJ1Og.png
//2px only black https://i.imgur.com/5z46WVp.png
//88x62px only black https://i.imgur.com/ZtGMUh9.png
//88x62px black and red https://i.imgur.com/67IZCaD.png
//220x297px black and red https://i.imgur.com/KTNnJGF.jpg

getPixels("https://i.imgur.com/KTNnJGF.jpg", function(err, ndarray) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Bad image path!");
        return;
    }

    const uintArr = new Uint8Array(ndarray.data);
    const regularArr = [];
    let oneColor = true;

    for(let i = 0, l = uintArr.length / 4; i < l; i++) {
        regularArr.push([uintArr[4*i], uintArr[4*i+1], uintArr[4*i+2], uintArr[4*i+3]])
    }
    for(let i = 0, l = regularArr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(regularArr[i + 1]) {
            let currentValString = JSON.stringify(regularArr[i]);
            let nextValString = JSON.stringify(regularArr[i + 1]);

            if(currentValString !== nextValString) {
                oneColor = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log('Is image one color? ', oneColor);
});
```

I don't know if it's most efficient but it works.