# Convert ndarray to array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using [ndarray](https://github.com/scijs/ndarray). I'm doing console log:

```
console.log(ndarray.data)
```

it's:

> Uint8Array [ 0, 0, 0, 255 ]

how can I convert it to array of arrays (array of array in above example) like this:

```
[[ 0, 0, 0, 255 ]]
```

---

When I have  Uint8Array like this one:

```
Uint8Array [
  0,   0,
  0, 255,
  0,   0,
  0, 255
]
```

then I would like it to be

```
[[ 0, 0, 0, 255 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 255 ]]
```

but with given answer it's

```
[ [
    0,   0,
    0, 255,
    0,   0,
    0, 255
  ] ]
```

Comment: Do you want to keep in ndarray or do you want a regular array?

Comment: regular array with arrays inside containing 4 numbers like in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
let u = new Uint8Array([ 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255 ]);
let a=[];

for(let i=0; i<u.length/4; i++) a.push([u[4*i],u[4*i+1],u[4*i+2],u[4*i+3]]);

console.log( a );
```

Comment: I want to split it every fourth so I will have array of arrays but this just create array of array, take a look at edit

Comment: Working just fine, cool, dzięki:). Can you take a look at my post and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749330/get-color-amount-with-get-image-colors-package/56753131#56753131 (I found answer by myself with your help here) , is it most efficient way of checking if an image contains more than one color?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this way

```js
let ua = new Uint8Array([ 0, 0, 0, 255 ]);

let aa = [[...ua]];

console.log( aa );
```